# SQL BigQuery Taking way too much time when using case Then to get columns

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

The issue at hand is that we need to "dynamically" retrieve tables columns with SQL.

Right now when we set ID and readStatus values, the query takes way longer than 3 minutes to run.

The idea is that we get all the other columns and the ones that are dynamic are, well, dynamic and are only retrieved when the variable calls for it.

```
declare var1 String;
declare var2 String;
declare var3 String;
declare var4 String;
declare var5 String;
declare cpeValue String;
declare readStatusValue String;

set var1 = "1_15";
set var2 = "2_3";
set var3 = "3_45";
set var4 = "4_6";
set var5 = "5_75";
set IDValue = "PT0002000003259606FA";
set readStatusValue = "null";

SELECT 
  ID,
  Read_Status,
  CASE 
    WHEN var1='1_15' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1_15
    WHEN var1='2_3' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2_3
    WHEN var1='3_45' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3_45
    WHEN var1='4_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4_6
    WHEN var1='5_75' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5_75
    WHEN var1='6_9' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_6_9
    WHEN var1='10_35' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_10_35
    WHEN var1='13_8' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_13_8
    WHEN var1='17_25' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_17_25
    WHEN var1='20_7' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_20_7
    WHEN var1='27_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_27_6
    WHEN var1='34_5' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_34_5
    WHEN var1='41_4' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_41_4
  ELSE 0
  END AS DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1,
  CASE 
    WHEN var2='1_15' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1_15
    WHEN var2='2_3' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2_3
    WHEN var2='3_45' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3_45
    WHEN var2='4_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4_6
    WHEN var2='5_75' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5_75
    WHEN var2='6_9' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_6_9
    WHEN var2='10_35' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_10_35
    WHEN var2='13_8' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_13_8
    WHEN var2='17_25' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_17_25
    WHEN var2='20_7' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_20_7
    WHEN var2='27_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_27_6
    WHEN var2='34_5' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_34_5
    WHEN var2='41_4' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_41_4
  ELSE 0
  END AS DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2,
  CASE 
    WHEN var3='1_15' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1_15
    WHEN var3='2_3' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2_3
    WHEN var3='3_45' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3_45
    WHEN var3='4_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4_6
    WHEN var3='5_75' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5_75
    WHEN var3='6_9' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_6_9
    WHEN var3='10_35' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_10_35
    WHEN var3='13_8' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_13_8
    WHEN var3='17_25' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_17_25
    WHEN var3='20_7' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_20_7
    WHEN var3='27_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_27_6
    WHEN var3='34_5' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_34_5
    WHEN var3='41_4' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_41_4
  ELSE 0
  END AS DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3,
  CASE 
    WHEN var4='1_15' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1_15
    WHEN var4='2_3' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2_3
    WHEN var4='3_45' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3_45
    WHEN var4='4_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4_6
    WHEN var4='5_75' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5_75
    WHEN var4='6_9' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_6_9
    WHEN var4='10_35' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_10_35
    WHEN var4='13_8' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_13_8
    WHEN var4='17_25' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_17_25
    WHEN var4='20_7' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_20_7
    WHEN var4='27_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_27_6
    WHEN var4='34_5' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_34_5
    WHEN var4='41_4' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_41_4
  ELSE 0
  END AS DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4,
  CASE 
    WHEN var5='1_15' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1_15
    WHEN var5='2_3' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2_3
    WHEN var5='3_45' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3_45
    WHEN var5='4_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4_6
    WHEN var5='5_75' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5_75
    WHEN var5='6_9' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_6_9
    WHEN var5='10_35' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_10_35
    WHEN var5='13_8' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_13_8
    WHEN var5='17_25' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_17_25
    WHEN var5='20_7' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_20_7
    WHEN var5='27_6' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_27_6
    WHEN var5='34_5' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_34_5
    WHEN var5='41_4' THEN DYNAMIC_COLUMN_41_4
  ELSE 0
  END AS DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5
FROM `Very.Big.Table`
WHERE ID = cpeValue
AND (readStatusValue = "null" or Read_Status = readStatusValue)
```

Right now the readStatus, when it has a value different from null, it takes a lot longer than just having the id and null.

Comment: I would be surprised if the `case` expressions are causing the problem.  I would also point out that you have have to read all the "dynamic" columns, which makes the query more expensive than just the columns you need.

Comment: Yeah, right now the readStatus, when it has a value different from null, it takes a lot longer than just having the id and null.

Comment: . . Well, it has to read all those columns which adds time -- particularly if some of the columns are large.

Comment: Before we had this, we had *, in that case it would also need to read all the columns right? So shouldn't it remain at the same processing time (before it was between 30 seconds to 1 minute)

Comment: . . I'm surprised the `case` expressions would triple the time, but that seems like pretty good evidence.

Comment: Due to the issue  you are facing and after check the @Mikhail Berlyant answer , I suggest you to open a support case  to verify this, also is recommended to view BigQuery job metrics and slot metrics using StackDriver Monitoring inspection On the GCP  Console, 1. Go to Monitoring -> Metrics Explorer
2. Select "BigQuery Project" as "Resource Type"
For metrics, you can find the available options [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery)
3. You can filter by project_id, job location, job type depending on what data you want

Answer (score 0):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
declare var1 String;
declare var2 String;
declare var3 String;
declare var4 String;
declare var5 String;
declare cpeValue String;
declare readStatusValue String;

set var1 = "1_15";
set var2 = "2_3";
set var3 = "3_45";
set var4 = "4_6";
set var5 = "5_75";
set cpeValue = "PT0002000003259606FA";
set readStatusValue = "null";

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT 
  ID,
  Read_Status,
  DYNAMIC_COLUMN_''' || var1 || ''' DYNAMIC_COLUMN_1,
  DYNAMIC_COLUMN_''' || var2 || ''' DYNAMIC_COLUMN_2,
  DYNAMIC_COLUMN_''' || var3 || ''' DYNAMIC_COLUMN_3,
  DYNAMIC_COLUMN_''' || var4 || ''' DYNAMIC_COLUMN_4,
  DYNAMIC_COLUMN_''' || var5 || ''' DYNAMIC_COLUMN_5
FROM `Very.Big.Table`
WHERE ID = "''' || cpeValue || '''" ''' || 
CASE 
  WHEN readStatusValue != "null" 
    THEN ''' AND Read_Status = "''' || readStatusValue || '''" '''
  ELSE ''' '''
END;
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work: Syntax error: Unclosed triple-quoted string literal

Comment: i just tested again and it works for me  - make sure you copy paste as it is in my answer w/o losing any chars!!

Comment: Ah wait yes, I know what you're going for let's see

Comment: Alright, got it working, and ...basically same time. But that's good cause now we know that it's not because of the cases!

Comment: Hahahaha, true!